# Get random result from API search

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple app that retrieves jokes using the [icanhazdadjoke API](https://icanhazdadjoke.com/api). There's a search event handler that fetches jokes according to a limit parameter with a default of 15. There's also a randomize button that calls the search method with a limit set to 1. Each time the randomize button is clicked, the same result appears, however--how can I instead get a random single search result?

Here's my search handler:

```
  // Default parameter
  getJokes(limit = 15) {
    this.setState({ isFetchingJokes: true });

    fetch(
      `https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search?term=${
        this.state.searchTerm
      }&limit=${limit}`,
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json'
        }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        const jokes = json.results;
        this.setState({
          jokes,
          isFetchingJokes: false
        })
      });
  };
```

When the randomize button is clicked, the search handler is called with a limit of 1 (it's being passed as a prop on the rendered component, which is from another file: `onRandomize={() => this.getJokes(1)}`)

Full code: 
[App.js](https://github.com/nataliecardot/dad-jokes/blob/master/src/App.js)
[retrieval-form.js](https://github.com/nataliecardot/dad-jokes/blob/master/src/components/retrieval-form.js)

Comment: Maybe it is not a problem in your code, its how the API works,  for the same searchTerm it returns the same results, so if you request always 1 it returns always the same. You can simulate the randomize by requesting 10 or 20 and then get one randomly.

Comment: I agree with F.bernal, judging from the API documentation, you get a random joke only when calling the API without a search term

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two ways you can get randomized single result

1. You have to randomize the result in back end and then limit to 1.

2.By using a function that set random one from the array

```
 randomJoke(arr) {
    var joke = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
    this.setState({jokes: [joke] });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

With api request you can’t but get all array and you pick random with this code

```
var joke = jokes[Math.floor(Math.random()*jokes.length)];
```